# I am looking to create an API endpoint route that returns txt in a json format -Python

Tags: python, api, routes, vuetify.js

I'm new to developing and my question(s) involves creating an API endpoint in our route. The api will be used for a POST from a Vuetify UI. Data will come from our MongoDB. We will be getting a .txt file for our shell script but it will have to POST as a JSON. I think these are the steps for converting the text file:
1)create a list for the lines of the .txt
2)add each line to the list
3) join the list elements into a string
4)create a dictionary with the file/file content and convert it to JSON

This is my current code for the steps:

```
import json

something.txt: an example of the shell script ###
f = open("something.txt")

create a list to put the lines of the file in
file_output = []

add each line of the file to the list
for line in f:
    file_output.append(line)

mashes all of the list elements together into one string
fileoutput2 = ''.join(file_output)
print(fileoutput2)

create a dict with file and file content and then convert to JSON
json_object = {"file": fileoutput2}
json_response = json.dumps(json_object)

print(json_response)
{"file": "Hello\n\nSomething\n\nGoodbye"}
```

I have the following code for my baseline below that I execute on my button press in the UI

```
@bp_customer.route('/install-setup/<string:customer_id>', methods=['POST'])
def install_setup(customer_id):
    cust = Customer()
    customer = cust.get_customer(customer_id)
    ### example of a series of lines with newline character between them.
    script_string = "Beginning\nof\nscript\n"
    json_object = {"file": script_string}
    json_response = json.dumps(json_object)

   
        get the install shell script content
        replace the values (somebody has already done this)
        attempt to return the below example json_response
    
    return make_response(jsonify(json_response), 200)
```

my current Vuetify button press code is here: so I just have to ammend it to a POST and the new route once this is established

```
 onClickScript() {
  console.log("clicked");
  axios
    .get("https://sword-gc-eadsusl5rq-uc.a.run.app/install-setup/")
    .then((resp) => {
      console.log("resp: ", resp.data);
      this.scriptData = resp.data;
    });
},
```

I'm having a hard time combining these 2 concepts in the correct way. Any input as to whether I'm on the right path? Insight from anyone who's much more experienced than me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your **question**? It is not possible to just give you "insight" or "input" in this format, as this is **not a discussion forum**. We are looking for something much more specific; see [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236 for guidance. As it stands, my recommendation is to try to find a tutorial for the tools you are using.

Comment: (Also, please make sure the code example has comment markers in the appropriate places.)

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path, but needlessly complicating things a bit. For example, the first bit could be just:

```
import json

with open("something.txt") as f:
    json_response = json.dumps({'file': f.read()})

print(json_response)
```

And since you're looking to pass everything through `jsonify` anyway, even this would suffice:

```
with open("something.txt") as f:
    data = {'file': f.read()}
```

Where you can pass `data` directly through `jsonify`. The rest of it isn't sufficiently complete to offer any concrete comments, but the basic idea is OK.

If you have a working whole, you could go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to ask for some reviews, you should limit questions on StackOverflow to actual questions about getting something to work.